# R: Replace multiple patterns and keep unique results

Tags: r, pattern-matching, substring

I have a dataframe of 98012x47 dimensions, the rownames for which are quite complex:

```
> head(rownames(exprs.gene))
[1] "XM_001722700 // LOC100132970"                                                                                                                                                                                   
[2] "NM_001005240 // OR4F17 /// NM_001004195 // OR4F4 /// NM_001005484 // OR4F5 /// BC136848 // OR4F17 /// BC136907 // OR4F4 /// ENST00000318050 // OR4F17 /// ENST00000335137 // OR4F4 /// ENST00000326183 // OR4F5"
[3] "XM_001713972 // LOC100132561"                                                                                                                                                                                   
[4] "XR_037798 // LOC100132630 /// XM_001713972 // LOC100132561 /// XR_042510 // LOC100131243"                                                                                                                       
[5] "XR_037798 // LOC100132630 /// XM_001713972 // LOC100132561"                                                                                                                                                     
[6] "XR_038367 // LOC100132769 /// XM_001720943 // LOC100130600 /// XM_001713972 // LOC100132561"
```

Each rowname is a string of substrings separated by // or ///. I want to remove *every substring* that starts with `XR_`, `NM_`, `XM_`, `BC` and `ENST` and keep the unique results only.

**For e.g.** the first row should look like: `LOC100132970` instead of `XM_001722700 // LOC100132970`.

**Another e.g.**: In the second row `NM_001005240 // OR4F17 /// NM_001004195 // OR4F4 /// NM_001005484 // OR4F5 /// BC136848 // OR4F17 /// BC136907 // OR4F4 /// ENST00000318050 // OR4F17 /// ENST00000335137 // OR4F4 /// ENST00000326183 // OR4F5` should be replaced by `OR4F17 // OR4F4 // OR4F5` i.e. only unique results should be kept.

How can I achieve that? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `grep` i.e. `!grepl('^(XR_|NM_|XM_|BC|ENST)', row.names(data))`

Comment: Ok you misunderstood my question - I will reframe it. I have also given two examples of what I want to achieve.

Comment: You cannot remove duplicates together with a unque occurrence of the duped elements. Use other techniques.